# how to measure page speed with javascript and cookies included without browser and tools like yslow/firebug

Tags: javascript, html, css, measurement, nagios

I'd like to measure the page speed of one of my projects in my terminal or like a HTML comment rendered at the bottom of any page like the results I'm getting from firebug in the "Network" tab.

If there is any way available I'd like to automate this and get the ability to monitor this with nagio or something like that.

Have anyone a good practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, what do you want to measure? The load time? The render time? The time to execute a Javascript?

Comment: i'd like to measure the time, a typical browser would need to load/render the hole page with cookies from "pixels" and all the javascript like jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Check into HTTPUnit, HTMLUnit, Selenium....

All of those you can jar and execute with a Nagios plugin - and they're pretty high level.

You could also use wget/ab and/or cURL, but they're only really good at grabbing monolithic pages (ie no css, etc).

Comment: wget, lynx and w3m did not load the tons of javascript or render different as any of the browsers user using.

tanks for the tip with selenium! I'll give it try.

Comment: Selenium is probably the easiest option.  You can use a real browser or use the HtmlUnit driver (warning: the javascript support is wonky and you have to specify it in the driver instance, but it mostly works...).